# Уведомление об отклонённых правках

Tags: предложение, статус-так-задумано, модерация, уведомления, предлагаемые-правки

Механизм правки для пользователей с низкой репутацией сейчас построен следующим образом:

1. пользователь редактирует чужой пост,
2. правка уходит на проверку,
3. несколько человек принимают решение о правильности правки.

Если правка принимается сообществом, то всё хорошо.

Если же правка спорная или некачественная, проверяющие могут оставить сообщение, которое, по идее, адресовано пользователю, совершившему правку.

*Насколько я понимаю*, при наличии голосов "против" пользователь не получает никакого уведомления об этом, и все комментарии уходят в воздух.

Если это так, то **предлагаю добавить** в механизм уведомлений **оповещения об отклонённых правках**.

Обычно пользователь не имеет много отклонённых правок, так что очередь оповещений не будет захламлена.
Более того, очень важно получать отзывы о правках, если они вызвали споры или оказались полностью не приняты сообществом, чтобы поправить своё поведение и понять политику правок.

---

Лично меня очень печалит, что мои комментарии о правках не видит тот, кому этот комментарий непосредственно направлен.

На месте человека, правку которого отклонили, я бы очень хотел увидеть эти комментарии, чтобы исправить своё поведение. Сейчас же платформа зачем-то скрывает факт негативной реакции сообщества и проверить, что правка не отклонена, можно только покопавшись с интерфейсом профиля (а начинающие далеко не так хорошо разбираются в том, что можно найти в интерфейсе и где).

Comment: Думаю, что не только окончательное отклонение правки, но и каждый голос за отклонение должен создавать уведомение, ведущее на страницу проверки. Бывает, что из трех пользователей нашелся только один адекватный. Пусть хотя бы его голос будет услышан.

Comment: @NickVolynkin так да, я это (хоть и не очень явно) назвал спорным случаем. Его, конечно, тоже хочется слышать.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky можно как-то озвучить причину для "статус-так-задумано"?

Comment: @alexolut Возможно, неудачная метка. Как говорится [в ответет Oceinic](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2121/6), это [уже реализовано](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137334/274323), возможно, немного в другом виде. Нотификации предназначены: (1) чтобы показать, где участник сделал правильное по мнению системы действие, (2) когда участник может незамедлительно что–то изменить. Информация о том, что предложенные изменения были отклонены, отображаются тогда, когда участник в следующий раз будет предлагать новые изменения, но лишь после того, как будет допущено N ошибок (отклонено N правок).

Answer (score 7):

Не так давно редактировал метку, а её не приняли. Я даже об этом не узнал. Только если целенаправленно зайти на своей странице в раздел предложений, то можно увидеть причину отклонения.

Удивлён, что до сих пор нету никаких уведомлений по этому поводу. Хотя бы можно было б юзеру отправлять сводку по его правкам: сколько приняли, сколько отклонили и почему.

Comment: Да, даже простая статистика, как по тревогам, и то недоступна.

Comment: Уведомления приходят о внесении _изменений в ваш_ вопрос или ответ (то есть если вы автор сообщения, а не автор правки).

Answer (score 7):

Такой механизм существует. Если Ваша правка была отклонена, в следующий раз когда Вы откроете форму правки, вверху её появится такое предупреждение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А если отклонённых правок было много, то такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)

Comment: Вы уверены, что эта функциональность включена на ruSO? Мои правки не отклонялись, поэтому не знаю, появляется ли такое сообщение у нас. В любом случае, здесь просто небольшая плашка и только при заходе в форму правки, а я предлагаю отправлять комментарии от проверяющих через механизм уведомлений, что гораздо проще заметить пользователю.

Comment: Да, у меня такое было. С тем, что предупреждения не особо заметны согласен

Comment: Хоть и не моментальное уведомление, но есть. Это лучше, чем ничего. Спасибо, что заметили.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а перевести сообщения?