# Не сообщается об отклоненных правках

Tags: обсуждение, предлагаемые-правки, отклонённые-правки

Только сегодня заметил, что ни как не сообщается об отклоненных правках.
Дополнил сегодня ответ: [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/270500).
И совершенно случайно (не закрыл вкладку) заметил что правка отменена.

Иногда дополняю ответы, с уверенностью что все правки проходят.
Вероятно и на остальные правки до этого время тоже потрачено напрасно.
Думаю просто необходимо оповещать об этом. Что бы можно было хоть какие то выводы сделать для себя.

Такой вопрос уже поднимался в 2015 году: [Уведомление об отклоненных правках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2110/%D0%A3%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85/2118)

Думаю я не один, напрасно трачу время на отклоняемые правки.

Comment: Просто не делайте такие странные правки

Comment: Здесь результаты по вашим правкам: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/270371/Максим?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: Андрей NOP, обсуждаем не конкретную правку, а необходимость оповещений.

Comment: С оповещениями беда. Для начала бы прикрутить оповещение "Пост за который вы недавно голосовали был изменён", чтоб минуса снимать. То же с закрывашками..

Comment: vp_arth, тоже важное оповещение.